# Basic Eclipse + Glassfish Error Servlet 404

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, localhost, http-status-code-404

I am studying J2EE through a video tutorial and stuck on first basic servlet. On the video the page loads successfully, but not on my browser. I have done everything as lecturer does. Server runs fine. Checked with 8080 and 4848. I have added servelet to glassfish as well, but still Error 404. Thank you.

```
package com.airline.controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class AddPassenger
 */
@WebServlet("/AddPassenger")
public class AddPassenger extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public AddPassenger() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
 response.setContentType("text/html");
 out.println("<html><body>");

 out.println("<h2>Welcome to My Airlines!!</h2>");

 out.println("</body></html>");


        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: what url do you check?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/web1/AddPassenger

Answer (score -1):

Select the **Glass Fish server**, right-click and select '**publish**'. Now refresh the page, this should work.